# PowerShell - Close File Before using Remove-Item

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script to inspect the contents of 2 .zip files, compare the names of a file in each .zip (as a datetime) and then remove the oldest of the 2 files. Everything seems to be working fine until it comes to the very end when I am trying to delete the oldest file with a simple 'Remove-Item' (I have tried the -Force option with no improvement). Every attempt I make results in this error:

> Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Scripts\Test2.zip: The process
>   cannot access the file 'C:\Scripts\Test2.zip' because it is being used
>   by another process. At line:44 char:5
>   +     Remove-Item $newLocation -Force
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Scripts\Test2.zip:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

This is the script I have come up with (be gentle, it's probably not the smoothest thing on earth):

```
$scriptLocation = "C:\Scripts\"
$oldLocation = "C:\Scripts\Test1.zip"
$newLocation = "C:\Scripts\Test2.zip"

cd $scriptLocation

$fileOld = .\GetZipContents.ps1 -FileName $oldLocation | Where {$_.FileExtn -eq ".txt"}
$fileNew = .\GetZipContents.ps1 -FileName $newLocation | Where {$_.FileExtn -eq ".txt"}

function Convert-DateString ([String]$Date, [String[]]$Format)
{
   $result = New-Object DateTime

   $convertible = [DateTime]::TryParseExact(
      $Date,
      $Format,
      [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
      [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
      [ref]$result)

   if ($convertible) { $result }
}

$oldName = $fileOld.FileName
$oldDate = $oldName.Substring(0,$oldName.Length-4)

$newName = $fileNew.FileName
$newDate = $newName.Substring(0,$newName.Length-4)


$convOldDate = Convert-DateString -Date $oldDate -Format 'MMMM_dd_yyyy'
$convNewDate = Convert-DateString -Date $newDate -Format 'MMMM_dd_yyyy'
$compare = $convOldDate -ge $convNewDate

If($compare -eq $True)
#OLD
{
    Remove-Item $oldLocation -Force
    "OLD FILE IS OLD - REMOVING: ({0})" -f ($oldLocation) 
}
Else
#NEW
{
    Remove-Item $newLocation -Force
    "NEW FILE IS NEW - REMOVING: ({0})" -f ($newLocation)
}
```

And this is the GetZipContents.ps1 being called in $fileOld and $fileNew:

```
[cmdletbinding()]            
param(            
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
 [string[]]$FileName,            
 [String]$ExportCSVFileName            
)            
#Exit if the shell is using lower version of dotnet            

$dotnetversion = [Environment]::Version            
if(!($dotnetversion.Major -ge 4 -and $dotnetversion.Build -ge 30319)) {            
 write-error "You do not have Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 installed. Script exiting..."            
 exit(1)            
}            

# Import dotnet libraries            

[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')            
$ObjArray = @()            
foreach($zipfile in $FileName) {            
if(Test-Path $ZipFile) {            
 $RawFiles = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile).Entries            
 foreach($RawFile in $RawFiles) {            

  $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $RawFile.Name            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FullPath -Value $RawFile.FullName            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CompressedLengthInKB -Value ($RawFile.CompressedLength/1KB).Tostring("00")            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnCompressedLengthInKB -Value ($RawFile.Length/1KB).Tostring("00")            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileExtn -Value ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($RawFile.FullName))            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ZipFileName -Value $zipfile            
  $ObjArray += $Object            
  if(!$ExportCSVFileName) {            
   $Object            
  }            
 }            
} else {            
 Write-Warning "$ZipFileInput File path not found"            
}            
if ($ExportCSVFileName){            
 try {            
  $ObjArray  | Export-CSV -Path $ExportCSVFileName -NotypeInformation            
 } catch {            
  Write-Error "Failed to export the output to CSV. Details : $_"            
 }            
}            

}
```

Which I got from here: http://techibee.com/powershell/reading-zip-file-contents-without-extraction-using-powershell/2152

I have run Handle.exe to find the process holding these files open, and it shows that the PowerShell ISE itself it the problem.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried to search for similar problems, but only found issues where other processes held open the file, which you can then kill with Handle.exe. I am not sure how to do this if PowerShell ISE needs to let go...

Answer (score 2):

Well sure, the thing is that you call `[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead()` but you never close the file. The last thing that you should be doing in your `If` scriptblock is closing the `OpenRead` that you started. The object that you are working with is a `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` which you can read about at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx

What you need to do is release the resources for the instance of that file that you have open with $Rawfiles. To do that you would call the `Dispose()` method. Where I would suggest doing that is just before your `Else` statement. So update your GetZipContents.ps1 script to look like this:

```
[cmdletbinding()]            
param(            
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
 [string[]]$FileName,            
 [String]$ExportCSVFileName            
)            
#Exit if the shell is using lower version of dotnet            

$dotnetversion = [Environment]::Version            
if(!($dotnetversion.Major -ge 4 -and $dotnetversion.Build -ge 30319)) { 
 write-error "You do not have Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 installed. Script exiting..."            
 exit(1)            
}            

# Import dotnet libraries            

[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')            
$ObjArray = @()            
foreach($zipfile in $FileName) {            
if(Test-Path $ZipFile) {            
 $RawFiles = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile).Entries            
 foreach($RawFile in $RawFiles) {            

  $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $RawFile.Name            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FullPath -Value $RawFile.FullName            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CompressedLengthInKB -Value ($RawFile.CompressedLength/1KB).Tostring("00")            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnCompressedLengthInKB -Value ($RawFile.Length/1KB).Tostring("00")            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileExtn -Value ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($RawFile.FullName))            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ZipFileName -Value $zipfile            
  $ObjArray += $Object            
  if(!$ExportCSVFileName) {            
   $Object            
  }            
 }
 $RawFiles.Dispose()            
} else {            
 Write-Warning "$ZipFileInput File path not found"            
}            
if ($ExportCSVFileName){            
 try {            
  $ObjArray  | Export-CSV -Path $ExportCSVFileName -NotypeInformation            
 } catch {            
  Write-Error "Failed to export the output to CSV. Details : $_"            
 }            
}            

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that GetZipContents.ps1 is not closing the file after it is done with it.  `ZipFile::OpenRead` returns a ZipArchive class ([documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx)), which implements `IDisposable`.  This indicates that the ZipFile archive needs to be Disposed.

Try this (note the call to Dispose:)

```
if(Test-Path $ZipFile) {
 $ZipArchive = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile)
 $RawFiles = $ZipArchive.Entries
 foreach($RawFile in $RawFiles) { 
   $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
   $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $RawFile.Name

   # etc. etc.

 }
 $RawFiles.Dispose()         
} else {            
  Write-Warning "$ZipFileInput File path not found"            
}
```

Reading up on [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) will explain some more.